# Rails4: Get an ActiveRecord::Relation from a model or an already chained relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm writing a module for ActiveRecord models. In short it's a method that can call a series of `where`, `join` and `order` statements. The statements are not known at the time of writing so it is not possible to use scopes. So far it works well but there is one point I'd like to improve.

Here is my method:

```
def filter
  rel = respond_to?(:filter_scope) ? filter_scope : where(1)
  # Do other stuffs with `rel`
  # ...
  rel
end
```

It first call `filter_scope` if it is defined, or it obtain an `ActiveRecord::Relation` from the target model. To do so I use `where(1)` to force the model to return a relation object. This works well  whenever I call `filter` directly on the model (`User.filter`) or on a relation (`User.order(:name).filter`, `User.my_scope.filter.order(:age)` etc...)

But using `where(1)` fells a bit dirty. In Rails 3 I would be using `all` instead but it's depreciated in Rails 4. Any idea on how to improve this?

Thanks in advance

---

Note: I cannot substitute `where(1)` by `self` because there is a possibility that `self` would be returned from `filter` and `User.filter` would be a class, therefore not usable as a query object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In Rails 3 I would be using all instead but it's depreciated in Rails 4.

I don't think `all` is depreciated, it used to return an `Array` (rails 3) and now returns an `ActiveRecord::Relation` so you should be able to use it for chaining queries.

see http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods.html#method-i-all

> Returns an ActiveRecord::Relation scope object.

Comment: I have no idea where and how, but I worked around that depreciation problem. Or perhaps it was in a dream, I should sleep less. Well, thanks for waking me up anyhow :)